Redefined xmlns in HTML elements
I'm using HTML Tidy (version 5.8.0) to clean up web-sourced HTML for transforming with XSLT.
This generally works fine until I discovered a page where 2 <use/> elements have identical repeated xmlns:xlink definitions.
example.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-search" href="#gel-icon-search" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-no" href="#gel-icon-no" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>

This goes unremarked when run through HTML Tidy:
$ tidy --output-xhtml 1 example.html > /dev/null
Info: Document content looks like XHTML 1.0 Transitional
No warnings or errors were found.

But it fatally trips up my XSLT processor and xmllint for the identical reason:
EDIT
To clarify, I'm using HTML Tidy via lib bindings within a Python script and the example HTML above is heavily simplified to demonstrate the exact issue only.  Use of command-line HTML Tidy here is for ease of replication.  I don't use xmllint in the script, but it is the simplest way to demonstrate the exact error shown by my XSL processor.
$ xmllint example.html
example.html:8: parser error : Attribute xmlns:xlink redefined
:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                                                               ^
example.html:11: parser error : Attribute xmlns:xlink redefined
:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                                                               ^

I would expect that HTML Tidy would normalise duplicated xmlns:xlink... attributes as it does for normal attributes (it keeps either first or last).
Stripping out the duplicated xmlns:xlink... is simple with sed but it is still double-handling.
Am I simply missing the correct Tidy option?
The following options make no difference:
--output-xml 1
--drop-proprietary-attributes 1
--doctype strict
--strict-tags-attributes 1
--repeated-attributes keep-first

I suspect this is a bug in Tidy and will submit it if there is no simple explanation.
EDIT
I understand that this is easily fixable with additional tools, the main point of this question is to establish whether HTML Tidy should be noticing/fixing this error or if it is beyond its scope.
Desired output from HTML Tidy:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-search" href="#gel-icon-search" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-no" href="#gel-icon-no" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>


Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

If you use the --input-xml 1 option, tidy will remove the duplicate xmlns:xlink... declarations. https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.8.0.html#input-xml

@mzjn thank you - this best answers the question, but with a caveat: from the link you posted, [input-xml] option specifies if Tidy should use the XML parser rather than the error correcting HTML parser.  So that option fixes the problem in my example HTML - and may well work for others reading this thread - but (for me) introduces other issues because the HTML parser is not being used. YMMV.
I'll submit this to the HTML Tidy maintainers and let them decide if it is a bug to output matching xmlns attributes when --output-xhtml is stipulated.

UPDATE: python only solution using lxml which is based on libxml2 as xmllint
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover = True)
tree = etree.parse("/home/lmc/tmp/test.html", parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True).decode('utf-8'))

Result:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-search" href="#gel-icon-search" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-no" href="#gel-icon-no" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>

Using xmllint --recover will show the warning but strip the double namespace declaration (better option than using sed).
xmllint --recover ~/tmp/test.html
Result
/home/lmc/tmp/test.html:8: parser error : Attribute xmlns:xlink redefined
:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                                                               ^
/home/lmc/tmp/test.html:11: parser error : Attribute xmlns:xlink redefined
:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                                                               ^
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-search" href="#gel-icon-search" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#gel-icon-no" href="#gel-icon-no" role="presentation"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>

Warning goes to stderr so it can be removed from output
xmllint --recover ~/tmp/test.html 2>/dev/null

To save the changes:
printf "%s\n" 'save' 'bye' | xmllint --recover --shell ~/tmp/test.html

xmlns:xlink=... it's a namespace declaration and not a regular attribute so --repeated-attributes keep-first won't work.
That namespace is used there on this attribute xlink:href="#gel-icon-no".
Using --shell option to get qualified attributes:
printf "%s\n" 'setns xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' 'cat //use/@xlink:href' 'bye' | xmllint --recover --shell ~/tmp/test.html 2>/dev/null
/ > setns xlink=http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
/ > cat //use/@xlink:href
 -------
 xlink:href="#gel-icon-search"
 -------
 xlink:href="#gel-icon-no"
/ > bye


That's an excellent point about the xmllint --recover flag and that would be a better fix than sed.  However, if I use xmllint on its own then I lose all the good things HTML Tidy does, and if I use it in conjunction with HTML Tidy then I'm back to double-handling.

@mike seems that tidy is not giving any chance to clean up namespaces so the double handling looks unavoidable. perhaps tidy stdout can be piped to xmllint to prevent duplicate file access. tidy <opts> file.xml | xmllint --recover - > newfile.xml.

@mike just added a python solution.

thanks for thinking outside the box, these look like useful workarounds.
